# SwiftUI DragGesture sets offset in infinite loop

Tags: swiftui

I want to drag one view within a `ZStack`. In this example code the `Toolbar` has a blue draggable area. It should move `Toolbar` around the screen, by setting the `offset`. Instead, it goes into an infinite loop. How can it be fixed to drag correctly?

It prints the following eternally:

> changed (36.5, 27.0)
> changed (0.0, 0.0)

```
extension CGPoint {
    func toSize() -> CGSize { .init(width:x, height:y) }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Toolbar(dragOffset: $offset)
                .offset(offset)
            Text(verbatim: "Offset: \(offset)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct Toolbar: View {
    @Binding var dragOffset: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Color.blue.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .gesture(drag)
            Color.green.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            Color.red.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }
    }
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                print("changed \(value.location)")
                dragOffset = value.location.toSize()
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                print("ended")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed to specify a `CoordinateSpace`, because the default is `.local`. Using `.global` works. A named space should also work.

It can also be helpful to record the initial offset in a `@State` variable and then set the new values using that starting value plus the drag's `translation`.

```
@State private var dragStartOffset: CGSize? = nil
...
DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
   .onChanged { value in
       if dragStartOffset == nil {
           dragStartOffset = dragOffset
       }
       dragOffset = dragStartOffset! + value.translation
   }
   .onEnded { _ in 
       dragStartOffset = nil
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just fine in my case.

Answer (score 6):

You should apply the `offset` before the `gesture`.

This ensures you don't create an infinite loop where you drag on the screen, the offset changes, which then changes the position of the view again. This means your gesture offset has now changed, hence creating an infinite loop.

Changes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Toolbar(dragOffset: $offset)
//                .offset(offset) // <- REMOVE THIS
            Text(verbatim: "Offset: \(offset)")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Toolbar: View {
    @Binding var dragOffset: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Color.blue.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .offset(dragOffset) // <- ADD THIS
                .gesture(drag)

            Color.green.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .offset(dragOffset) // <- ADD THIS

            Color.red.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .offset(dragOffset) // <- ADD THIS
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: could you explain why is this making a difference? The offset changes the position of the view in both cases, why should the order matter? Thanks

Comment: @BalázsVincze The key here is that you need to apply the offset _before_ handling the gesture. The reason why is because you can imagine the `Toolbar` (and contained `HStack`) won't be offset at all now. Only the inner `Color` views will - and the `gesture` modifier kind of "creates a new view" which isn't affected by the offset. If this was the other way around like originally, the view with the gesture will also be offset, further offsetting the gesture. Hope that made some sense :p